# Messaging Addon: You are not authorized to perform this action

Tags: add-on, addons

I am trying to send a private message using http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/messaging.html:

```
{exp:messaging:pm_compose
    class="form-horizontal"
    return="SAME_PAGE"
    save_sent="yes"
    skip_success_message="yes" 
}
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value='{exp:channel:entries channel="profiles" entry_id="{segment_2}"}{screen_name}{/exp:channel:entries}'/>
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value=""/>
        <textarea class="span12" rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send Message</button>
    </fieldset>
{/exp:messaging:pm_compose}
```

When I go to the page that contains the above code, I get the following error:

```
You are not authorized to perform this action
```

I'm using Safecracker Registration -- and that's why I have to get the `{screen_name}` that way (it gets it correctly). Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user was not in a member group that could send private messages. Problem solved.